# Вставить код из переменной в body не потеряв код из библиотек

Tags: javascript, body

У меня имеется задача - вставить код в body из переменной.

`document.body.innerHTML = text;` InnerHTML хорошо справляется с данной задачей. Но он убирает все элементы которые оставляют библиотеки. В моем случае `notyf`. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: document.body.innerHTML += text;

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) — это не разрушит возможные привязки обработчиков событий к элементам библиотек.